# SQLite Fincas con suma de ingresos y gastos

Tags: sqlite

Estoy intentando reproducir una aplicación de Alquileres de fincas, hecha con FileMaker en SQLite.

Quiero obtener, de cada finca y año, los ingresos y gastos. Las tablas involucradas son las siguientes: Finques(Fincas), Lloguers(Ingresos), Despeses(Gastos).

He utilizado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT f.finca, l.anyo año,  sum(l.total) Ingresos, sum(d.total) Gastos
FROM Finques f
JOIN Lloguers l ON l.fincaID = f.fincaID AND l.anyo = d.anyo
JOIN Despeses d ON f.fincaID = d.fincaID AND l.anyo = d.anyo
GROUP BY f.finca, l.anyo
ORDER by f.finca, l.anyo
```

Los totales de los ingresos están multiplicado por el número de registros de los gastos y viceversa. Con la misma fórmula, haciendo ingresos y gastos por separado funciona

Adjunto los totales agrupados e individualmente.

[image: Totales con ingresos y gastos]

[image: Totales de ingresos]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por adelantado

```
fincaID,serial,referencia,finca,municipi
```

C6C26524-7025-46D1-B93B-18889180031A,1,FIN001,Ciudad,Mongat
88A42D2B-1FA4-4E90-9EE9-0F39203FC7C0,2,FIN002,d' Osona 10,Mongat
C3F114C8-050C-444B-84DE-3BDDAD118B5B,3,FIN003,d' Osona 8,Mongat

```
lloguerID,finca,anyo,total,fincaID,pisID,llogaterID
```

5237DB36-F6DA-4648-A30D-B05E7DE34124,d' Osona 8,2009,1134.04,C3F114C8-050C-444B-84DE-3BDDAD118B5B,3AAFFCB8-716B-4A36-A13E-D18223372239,
5EE7A99E-61A0-41F1-8D2D-FA32667C9155,d' Osona 10,2009,1136.95,88A42D2B-1FA4-4E90-9EE9-0F39203FC7C0,C314C03A-F621-4866-AD4D-80BA0B3EB77A,69B45437-090C-4A26-801F-AC93D80D8836

```
despesaID,finca,total,proveidorID,fincaID,pisID,anyo
```

C7C5D5D8-C4CC-4E97-8756-77B8B5D3A574,d' Osona 10,197.92,1F24813F-B8E5-4D83-B52D-F99E41B48E8C,88A42D2B-1FA4-4E90-9EE9-0F39203FC7C0,C314C03A-F621-4866-AD4D-80BA0B3EB77A,2009
EAD02493-6B76-444D-97FB-D554D61D9778,d' Osona 8,197.92,1F24813F-B8E5-4D83-B52D-F99E41B48E8C,C3F114C8-050C-444B-84DE-3BDDAD118B5B,3AAFFCB8-716B-4A36-A13E-D18223372239,2009
999800F5-7D61-4658-A273-67430FAEADD0,Aldea Mar,21.84,711521CD-0F8A-4A5E-BA3B-3B7895A4D335,C6C26524-7025-46D1-B93B-18889180031A,A80DD749-3F4F-48A8-BEE1-5769776D24B5,2009

Comment: El join no es correcto. Estas joineando registros demas al igualar los años entre ingresos y egresos. No deberia ser solo contra la tabla fincas?

Comment: Soy consciente que el Join no es correcto, como comento lo mío es FileMaker no domino SQL. Puede que tengas razón que sea sólo contra la tabla Fincas, pero sin más explicación no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Al no tener tus datos, es dificil ayudarte. por favor, pon un ejemplo de tus datos.

Comment: @gbianchi he puesto debajo de mi consulta unos datas de fincas, ingresos y gastos. Espero que te sirva